# Why does this functor ("lambda") give a weird warning?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, anonymous-types, functor

When I compile and run this with Visual C++ 2010:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int subtrahend = 5;

    struct Subtractor {
        int &subtrahend;
        int operator()(int minuend) { return minuend - subtrahend; }
    } subtractor5 = { subtrahend };

    std::cout << subtractor5(47);
}
```

I get the correct answer, 42.

Nevertheless, the compiler complains that this is impossible:

> Temp.cpp(9) : warning C4510: `main::Subtractor` : *default constructor could not be generated*
> Temp.cpp(6) : *see declaration of* `main::Subtractor`
>
> Temp.cpp(9) : warning C4512: `main::Subtractor` :  *assignment operator could not be generated*
> Temp.cpp(6) : *see declaration of* `main::Subtractor`
>
> Temp.cpp(9) : warning C4610: `struct main::Subtractor` ***can never be instantiated** - user defined constructor required*

What's going on?

Comment: How can you get `42` as answer? Is `48-5` equal to `42` ?

Comment: @Nawaz: Lol, good catch. It's because I was originally testing with 48, but then I thought 47 would be a more interesting example, so I put down 42. The 47 crept back in during a copy/paste error. :P

Comment: Why did you think `47` would be "more" interesting example? What is so special about it? Is your age? :P

Comment: There is no lambda in this code.

Comment: @Nawaz: LOL no, I'm nowhere near 42. :P I just thought an end result of 42 might be better, so I changed 48 to 47. (Regretting that now, though, haha)

Comment: @Ajay: It's *simulating* a lambda, hence why I put it in quotes...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first two warnings are just letting you know that the implicitly declared member functions cannot be generated due to the presence of a reference data member.

The third warning is [a Visual C++ compiler bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/488660/improper-issuance-of-c4610).

All three warnings can be ignored with no ill effects, though you can easily make all three go away by making the reference data member a pointer instead (reference data members are almost never worth the trouble).

Comment: +1 seems to be the right answer -- changing `int &` to `int` makes the third warning go away too! Didn't expect it to be a bug; interesting, thanks...

Answer (score 1):

The first warning is to tell you that a reference value cannot be defaultly constructed(references are guaranteed to point to some value). Switch the subtrahend to a regular integer and the problem will go away.

I am pretty sure the second warning is of similar nature.

(Just saying, it is generally much better to rely on something like boost::function or a similar implementation(std::tr1::function?) instead of writing this code manually)

Comment: I'm actually using an older compiler (so no TR1), I just tested it with VC 2010 to make sure it wasn't a compiler issue (which it partially was!). And I'm trying to keep away from Boost since this was supposed to be something lightweight, but +1 for the idea anyhow.

Comment: @Ethan: the second warning is indeed of similar nature. A reference cannot be reseated, thus you cannot assigned to it (it would assign to the referree).

Answer (score 0):

It's because the variable subtractor5 is an unnamed struct.  If you want to make the errors go away, give the structure used for subtractor5 a name.

For example:

```
struct subtractor {
 :
} subtractor5 = { subtrahend };
```

I unfortunately don't know enough C++ language-ese to know why it works, but I do know why the warning happens.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand this correctly, but I tried replacing `struct {` with `struct Subtractor {` and it didn't change anything. (Just updated my question too.)

Comment: Interesting.  I keyed on the "unnamed" aspect, not the rest of the error.

Comment: Exactly the same thing here -- I'd definitely seen this error before, regarding the default constructor/reference variables. I just totally missed that possibility because of the unnamed issue (and because of the third error).

Answer (score 0):

A user defined constructor is mandatory in following cases:

- Initializing constant data members (`const int c_member;`).
- Initializing reference data members (`int & r_member;`)
- Having a data member whose type doesn't have default constructor. Eg:

  class NoDefCtor
  {
  public: 
     NoDefCtor(int);
  };

  class ContainThat
  {
     NoDefCtor no_ctor_member;
  };
- Inheriting from a base class, where base class doesn't have default constructor. Almost same as above (`NoDefCtor`).

Comment: Do not forget the virtual inheritance of a base class without a default constructor too.